# Failed to instantiate module dataAccessService due to: Error: [$injector:nomod]

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Browser is throwing me this error Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module dataAccessService due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'dataAccessService' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

What is causing this?

I've tried switching up the script files and such but none give me any success. Routes do work but service inside won't

```
module app { 
    const app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute","dataAccessService"]);
    app.config(routeConfig);

    // routeConfig.$inject["$routeProvider"];

    function routeConfig($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/drivers', {
                templateUrl: './src/pages/drivers.html',
                controller: 'DriversListCtrl'
            })
            // .when('/teams', {
            //     templateUrl: './src/pages/teams.html',
            //     controller: 'teamsController'
            // })  
            // .otherwise({
            //     redirect:'/drivers'
            // })
    }
}
```

and my service

```
module app.service {

    export interface IDataAccessService {
        getApi():ng.IPromise<IDriver>;
    }

    export interface IDriver {
        name:string;
        team:string;
        points:number;
    }

    export class DataAccessService implements IDataAccessService {


        static $inject = ['$http'];
        constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService) {

        }
        getApi():ng.IPromise<IDriver>{
            return this.$http.get('https://ergast.com/api/f1/2013/driverStandings.json')
            .then((response:ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<IDriver>):IDriver=>{ 
                return response.data;
            })
        }
    }

    angular.module("app",[]).service("dataAccessService", DataAccessService)
}
```

finally the controller

```
module app.driversList {
    export interface IDriversList {
        fullName:any;
    }

    export class DriversListCtrl implements IDriversList {
        fullName:any;

        static $inject = ["dataAcessService"];
        constructor(private dataAcessService:app.service.DataAccessService){

            this.dataAcessService.getApi().then((data:app.service.IDriver):void=>{
                this.fullName = data;
            })
        }



    }

    angular.module("app",[]).controller("DriversListCtrl", DriversListCtrl)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have added the non-existent `dataAccessService` module to `app` module dependencies here:

```
const app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute","dataAccessService"]);
                                                      \
                                                       there is no such module
```

You should either define a module with `angular.module("dataAccessService", [])` and register your controller and a service within it, or just remove it from `app` dependencies:

```
const app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]);
```

Also it looks like you have a typo in your controller, that will lead to exception too:

```
                          should be Access, not Acess
                         /
static $inject = ["dataAcessService"];
constructor(private dataAcessService:app.service.DataAccessService){
                          \
                           should be Access, not Acess
```